# How to add buttons to header in navigation page in qooxdoo mobile

Tags: mobile, qooxdoo

I am using qooxdoo mobile 3.5. Is it possible to add custom buttons to the default header in a navigation page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible this way:

```
var button = new qx.ui.mobile.navigationbar.Button("foo");

page.getLeftContainer().add(button); page.getRightContainer().add(button);
```

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage~getLeftContainer!method_public